# Add attribute to Views VBO field

Tags: views

I have a view that displays a list of coupons that a user has earned. These coupons are provided by sponsoring companies and are not used on my site. Rather than doing an API integration to find out when a coupon is used, I just have a VBO view that allows users to mark coupons as "used".

Is it possible to disable the VBO checkbox if the coupon has been marked used? Or is this even the right approach to the issue?

As far as I know, the only real way to do this is by adding `disabled` attribute to the checkbox's `<input>` tag.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your question is?

Comment: Updated post to more clearly state question

Comment: How are those coupons implemented, are they just nodes? Or maybe some custom entity? Also, instead of "disable of the VBO checkbox", how about a solution where used coupons are just no longer shown in the (VBO) list of views? Eventually combined with an extra views tab that lists (only) the used coupons. If you agree, I'll post a (straight forward) answer about how to implement this.